# What value does Breeze offer to applications built with WebAPI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, breeze

Please forgive me if this question is too general, but what value does Breeze offer?  It seems like the biggest sells are change-tracking and thin "bare minimum" queries, but isn't that stuff the responsibility of a service layer?  Why has it become convenient to perform these operations on the client?

I've looked at the samples and it seems like a lot of server-side responsibility is creeping up to the clients with Breeze.  I've traditionally built my SPAs with different DTOs for different scenarios in the application to define what goes on the wire serverside.  CRUDding that data is just a matter of making the right API call from JS.

This strategy, in my opinion, makes it easier for other developers to build clients too.  All they need to know about are the API endpoints and JSON structure.  With breeze, they need to know more.

I'm just having a hard time seeing the value of this library - though I want to!  Any info/discussion here would be awesome.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Breeze enables the possibility of creating your queries in JavaScript (view models) *client side* easily and pushing your queries through a breeze controller.

Breeze wraps the Entity Framework into a JavaScript framework and offers the power of building queries client-side, but *still* executing them server-side . It contains a lot of additional functionality and makes your DB data completely available through a JavaScript layer.

To call some efforts:

- its API is familiar to LINQ
- change tracking (as you mentioned)
- client side caching *(efficiency!)*
- asynchrounous operations with promises

It depends of course how rich your client application is going to be. But SPAs are rather Rich Internet Applications ([RIA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_Application)). Due to their usual complex architecture Breeze makes it easy to implement a well designed JS data access.

### EDIT

Imagine you'd like to implement a grid, which allows to modify multiple DB objects like `Person`s.
Third party grids (like Kendo) usually support client side validation to improve user expierence and bandwidth use. Even though internet apps have to validate data server-side, bone head mistakes should be caught client-side before submitting them to the backend. Breeze offers you easy implementation of client-side validation.

Comment: > "makes your DB completely available through a JavaScript layer."  Why is this a good thing?  (Thank you for your response, by the way.)

Comment: I corrected it to "DB data". Actually you build your JS query in LINQ-style, push it through the `BreezeController` controller on your server and execute it through Entity Framework. Afterwards you retreive your data in your JS code. Then you could bind it, for example. And that with a very few amount of code.

Comment: Thanks so much ebeeb.  I'm going to spend a bunch of time on the angular/breeze template to wrap my head around it - I feel "dirty" right now for querying clientside but maybe the app will clear things up more :)  cheers!

Comment: Very nice explanation, ebeeb